# Why linux show only 1 process running?

Tags: linux

I watch a video, open a browser, etc. but the top command only shows 1 running process?

[image: top]

Comment: 375 is the total number of tasks. Most of them are sleeping. I would expect for example a browser to be mostly in the sleep state. Even rendering a video could sleep between rendering of individual frames. How exactly would you define "running" in the sense that you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "running" field in top displays the count of runnable tasks contending for CPU access, rather than the number of tasks currently running concurrently.

a more appropriate label would probably be "ready to run"

Comment: how i can look number of tasks currently running concurrently?

Comment: @Betflop Exactly one is running. Even on a single core CPU without SMT one thread can always run, except when interrupted by kernel work and if there is only one thread that is "ready to run", it will run.

Comment: Why if I have 8 cores why not 8 processes?

Comment: @Betflop Because there isn't anything more to do.

Comment: @Betflop if you want to see, how many processes are currently running, you could try this ```ps -e --no-headers | wc -l````